# Swift errors when handling data from server, json

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, error-handling

I converted my project from Objective-C to Swift but I ran into some errors.

**First set of errors:**

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CellIdentifier = "Cell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier)!

    if cell != cell {
        cell = CustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
    }

    // Configuring the cell
    Data * dataObject

    if !isFiltered {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            dataObject = followedArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.populateCell(dataObject, isFollowed: true, indexPath: indexPath, parentView: self)
        }
        else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            dataObject = dataArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.populateCell(dataObject, isFollowed: false, indexPath: indexPath, parentView: self)
        }
    }
    else {
        dataObject = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.populateCell(dataObject, isFollowed: false, indexPath: indexPath, parentView: self)
    }
    return cell
}
```

**Here is a picture of the errors:**

[image]

**Here is the Data NSObject Class**

```
class Data: NSObject {

//Strings
var dataName: String?
var dataID: String?
var dataStatus1: String?
var dataStatus2: String?
var dataURL: String?

override init() {

}

//Converting Strings into Objects

init(dataName dName: String,
     andDataStatus1 dStatus1: String,
     andDataStatus2 dStatus2: String,
     andDataURL dURL: String,
     andDataID dID: String)
{

    super.init()

    self.dataName = dName
    self.dataStatus1 = dStatus1
    self.dataStatus2 = dStatus2
    self.dataURL = dURL
    self.dataID = dID

 }

}
```

Thats the first set of errors.

**Now the Second Set of errors**

This code is for retrieving the data from the server

```
// Retrieving Data from Server
func retrieveData() {

    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!
    let data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
    jsonArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: kNilOptions, error: nil)

    // Setting up data array
    dataArray = NSMutableArray()

    // Looping through jsonArray
    for i in 0..<jsonArray.count {
        // Create Data Object
        let dID: String = jsonArray[i]["id"] as! String!
        let dName: String = jsonArray[i]["dataName"]
        let dStatus1: String = jsonArray[i]["dataStatus1"]
        let dStatus2: String = jsonArray[i]["dataStatus2"]
        let dURL: String = jsonArray[i]["dataURL"]

        // Add Data Objects to Data Array
        dataArray.append(Data(dataname: dName, andDataStatus1: dStatus1, andDataStatus2: dStatus2, andDataURL: dURL, andDataID: dID))
    }

    self.myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Here is a picture of the errors:**

[image]

[image]

I tried renaming some of the code from the errors but that just ended with more errors so I left it as originally converted. I'm learning Swift but these are deeper side of coding but in fixing it, I will be learning a lot more. Thank you for any help!

New Fixes/ Errors

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not convert to Swift very well at all.  And the error log basically explains everything that is wrong very well.

**Line 109**

```
var dataObject: Data
```

**Line 227**

```
jsonArray = JSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)
```

**Line 230**

```
var dataArray = []
```

**Line 235+**

```
let dID: String = jsonArray[i].objectForKey("id") as! String!
...
let dURL: NSURL = jsonArray[i].objectForKey("dataURL") as! NSURL
```

**Line 242**

```
dataArray.append(Data(dataname: dName, andDataStatus1: dStatus1, andDataStatus2: dStatus2, andDataURL: dURL, andDataID: dID))
```

Comment: That cleared a good bit of errors, thank you for helping, I did horribly with the converting. I added a new screen shot of the new errors at the bottom of the post.

Comment: You have a lot of Swift issues here.  I suggest you read [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) to get familiar with it.  And the rest is clearly explained in the errors.

Comment: I have but I'm just not familiar with the errors codes, since I'm new I don't know what xcode means when it gives me an error

Comment: As soon as you implement a solution and subsequently update your question showing new errors, your question goes from a genuine question to wanting to be handheld through fixing your errors. I suggest you try and research these errors first before rapid-firing your error logs.

Comment: @Aaron I understand and I'm working on the errors but it doesn't take long to figure out that I'm still lost in the errors with the new solutions

Answer (score 0):

> I converted my project from Objective-C to Swift

Mmmm, not exactly. This line:

```
Data * dataObject
```

is not, in any way, shape, or form, Swift. It seems to be still Objective-C. Write *Swift* code.

Also, do not try to define a Data class, as there is already a Swift Data type.

(There is a lot more wrong with your code, obviously, but I'm not going to try to cover it all. The question is really too broad; you're just flailing at this point.)

Comment: With the 20+ errors that appeared that little simple code escaped my mind, thank you!